# Could Cloudflare slow down writing process to database?

Tags: linux, wordpress, cache, cloudflare, cdn

I have two identical WordPress sites - live and staging - both sitting in the same EC2 server. The live is using Cloudflare, the staging is not. I noticed that database writing processes are slower in the live site.

Have you experienced this? Could Cloudflare slow down writing process to database? If so, how could I rectify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudflare sits outside your server, between the user and the web server. The web server (Wordpress on PHP) communicates directly with the database. There is no way Cloudflare is slowing communication between Wordpress and the database.

If you expand your question to "could cloudflare make my website slower?", the answer is yes, though it would be unusual. We would need more details to work that out. In that case please ask a more general question, which would be distinct from this fairly specific question you've asked.